# Android customized launcher screen vs theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-launcher

I'm trying to design a customized android launcher screen for my android device.What i meant launcher here is the Launching screen which we see,when we boot our Android device.I got confused with launcher and Theme.
This is the answer where i got from this http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/753255-difference-between-android-theme-vs-launcher.html

Basicly the launcher only affects the home screens and app drawer. If you mean a theme for like Cyanogen mod etc, it can change the look of everything, menus, statusbar, notification tray etc..

I am really interested in know the area where exactly these two differs(as both of them are meant for customizing the screen)?

Comment: In Manifest file, launcher refers to the icon of the application while theme is the style applied to activities

Comment: @Jibran Khan Thanks for your reply,What i meant launcher here is the Launching screen which we see,when we boot our Android device